# How to add labels for only some of the data point?

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to create a chart.js scatter plot with a set of points with values of 0 to 100 percent. I'd like to have 0 be a red point and 100 be blue and have a gradient between the two. I'm able to get the colors I want, but is it possible to get labels for just a few points like 0, 25, 50, 75, and 100? I don't want a label for all 101 possible values just enough for users to understand that it's a spectrum.

I considered trying to add two datasets to the chart one for the real data with no labels and another with not data but the five labels I want. Would this work?

Comment: Do you mean **labels on the axis**, or those **popup-thingies** directly **on the data points**? Could you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the ticks you want with the `afterBuildTicks` hook. You can also specify the `count` property in the ticks this will make it so chart.js generates that many ticks but you dont have control over the values of those ticks:

```js
const data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  data.push({
    x: i,
    y: i
  })
}

const options = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: data,
      borderColor: 'orange',
      backgroundColor: 'orange'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        afterBuildTicks: (a) => (a.ticks = [{
          value: 0
        }, {
          value: 25
        }, {
          value: 50
        }, {
          value: 75
        }, {
          value: 100
        }]),
        ticks: {
          count: 5, // limit to 4 ticks but let chart.js decide what tose ticks are
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```